# A harmonic function $\varphi$ with $D\varphi \in L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ is constant.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $\varphi$ be an harmonic function such that $D\varphi \in L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ for $q \in (1, +\infty)$. I read in *Partial Differential Equations* of *Quin Han* and *Fanghua Lin* that for $q = 2$, $\varphi$ has to be constant. My professor told me that it is possible to generalize this result to any $q \in (1,+\infty)$ but I couldn't find a reference of this anywhere. Would someone please tell me where I could find a proof ?

Comment: They deduce this result from the fact that, for a harmonic function and any $R \in (0, 1]$, 
$$\int_{B_{R/2}} | \varphi|^2 \le \theta \int_{B_R} |\varphi|^2 \quad\text{and}\quad \int_{B_{R/2}} |D \varphi|^2 \le \theta \int_{B_R} |D\varphi|^2$$
with $\theta \in (0,1).$ Is that what you meant by "$D\varphi \in L^2$ forces $\varphi$ to be bounded"?

Comment: No, this is not what I thought, but still. Do you think these inequalities remain true if $2$ is replaced by $q$?

Comment: Well.. I don't really know. It is not quite obvious that we can replace $2$ by $q$ is the proof..

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this question. Did you find something, meanwhile? It is interesting.

Comment: Yes, I found a proof: If $\phi$ is harmonic then so is $\partial_i \phi$. Therefore we just have to prove that an harmonic function $\psi \in L^q$ is zero. But, by using the mean value theorem and Holder's inequality we have
\begin{align*}
       |\psi(x)| &\le \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}  \int_{B(x, r)} |\psi(y)|~dy\\
        &\le \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\|\psi\|_{q} |B(x, r)|^{1/q'}\\
        &= \|\psi\|_q |B(x, r)|^{-1/q'} \to 0
    \end{align*}

Comment: Great! (I think you have a typo in the right-hand side of the very last identity, the exponent is $-1/q$). Why don'y you just cut&paste this comment into an answer? I will upvote it and it would be much easier to find in the future.